# Problem in $L^p$ spaces.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

$\textbf{Problem:}$ Let $(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ a measure space $\sigma$-finite, $p,q \in [1, \infty)$ conjugates and $\vert f \vert < \infty$ $\mu$-a.e. Define for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$

$$ f_n(x) = f(x) \hspace{0.3cm} \text{if} \hspace{0.3cm} \vert f(x) \vert \leq n \hspace{1cm} \text{and} \hspace{1cm} f_n(x)=0 \hspace{0.3cm} \text{if} \hspace{0.3cm} \vert f(x) \vert >n $$

Suppose that for all $g\in L^q$ :

$$\lim_{n} \int f_n g < \infty $$

Prove that for all $g\in L^q$

$$ \int fg < \infty \hspace{1cm} \text{and} \hspace{1cm} f \in L^p  $$

$\textbf{My attempt:}$ Consider $E= \{x \in X / \vert f(x) \vert  = \infty \}$ then $\mu(E)=0$. For each $x\in X \setminus E$ we have that exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\vert f(x) \vert \leq n_0$ and so for all $n>n_0:$ $\vert f(x) \vert \leq n$. Hence

$$ f_n(x)=f(x), \forall n>n_0 $$

Let $g \in L^q$, so $\vert f_n(x) g(x) \vert  = \vert f(x)g(x) \vert $ for all $x\in X\setminus E$ and for all $n>n_0$. Hence $\vert f_n g\vert  \rightarrow \vert fg \vert$ $\mu-$a.e. Note that $\vert f_n g \vert \leq \vert f_{n+1} g \vert $ so by monotone convergence theorem we have

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int \vert f_n g \vert = \int \vert fg \vert $$

By hypothesis we have $\int \vert fg \vert < \infty $ and then $\int fg < \infty $.

I can´t prove that $f \in L^p$. Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if all of the details in your problem are as they are supposed to be. I think the problem should be stated more like the following.

**Problem** Let $(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space, $p,q\in[1,\infty)$ with $1/p+1/q=1$ and $|f|<\infty$ $\mu$-a.e. For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ define $f_{n}$ by
$$f_{n}(x)=f(x) \mbox{ if } |f(x)|\leq n \mbox{ and } f_{n}(x)=0\mbox{ otherwise.}$$
Suppose that $$\lim_{n}\int_{X}|f_{n}g|\,d\mu<\infty,\mbox{ for all }g\in L^{q}$$
Prove that  $$\int_{X}|fg|\,d\mu<\infty,\mbox{ for all }g\in L^{q}$$
and that $f\in L^{p}$.

**Proof** (In the case that $(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ is finite). For $n\in\mathbb{N}$ define $\phi_{n}:L^{q}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$) by
$$\phi_{n}(g)=\int_{X}f_{n}g\,d\mu,\mbox{ for all }g\in  L^{q}.$$
Since $(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ is finite one clearly has that $\|f_{n}\|_{p}<\infty$ for each $n$, and so by Holder's inequality
$$|\phi_{n}(g)|\leq\int_{X}|f_{n}g|\,d\mu\leq\|f_{n}\|_{p}\|g\|_{q}<\infty$$
for all $g\in L^{q}$. That is, $\phi_{n}$ is bounded with $\|\phi_{n}\|\leq\|f_{n}\|_{p}$. Now, by using the Monotone Convergence Theorem argument in your attempt, one concludes that
$$\phi_{n}(g)\rightarrow\phi(g)$$
as $n\rightarrow\infty$ for all $g\in L^{q}$, where
$$\phi(g)=\int_{X}fg\,d\mu,\mbox{ for all }g\in L^{q}.$$
That is, $\phi_{n}\rightarrow\phi$ pointwise on $L^{q}$. Now, here's the important part. By the Uniform Boundedness Principle, since each $\phi_{n}$ is bounded, we may conclude that $\phi$ is also bounded. That is, $\phi\in(L^{q})^{\ast}\cong L^{p}$. Using facts about duality for $L^{p}$ spaces this allows us to conclude that there exists some $h\in L^{p}$ such that
$$\int_{X}fg\,d\mu=\phi(g)=\int_{X}hg\,d\mu,\mbox{ for all }g\in L^{q}.$$
But this is sufficient to conclude that $f=h$ $\mu$-a.e. and so $f\in L^{p}$ also. The second part of the problem now follows easily by Holder's inequality, since for any $g\in L^{q}$ one has that
$$\int_{X}|fg|\,d\mu\leq\|f\|_{p}\|g\|_{q}<\infty.$$